# Create new Google Workspace account and send sign-in instruction automatically using API

Tags: google-api, google-workspace, google-directory-api

As a new user onboarding process, I'm creating new account in workspace using API.
I'm using below API to create new account:

```
https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users
```

New account gets created in google workspace, now we would like to send the 'sign-in instruction' email to secondary mail address automatically.

How this can be achieved? which API can be used here?

When we create new account manually in google at that time we have option to preview and send sign-in instruction to secondary mail, same process we would like to automate.

with user api only user gets created but no sign-in instruction gets send automatically.